# DataTables ColReorder scroll when header scrolled close to boundaries

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables for a large quantity of data gathered from various ASP databases.
In addition, I am using the following DataTables plug-ins:
FixedHeaders, FixedColumns, ColReorder.

Now, with the ColReorder function, when a header (a column actually) is dragged to reorder it and is overflowing to the sides (horizontal scrolling), I would like the table to scroll to the side with it, so that the column can be dragged not only to the viewed area of the table but to the entire table.

I have tried nomerous ways and walkarounds such as trying to make it scroll when the curser is close to the boundaries (like here in "Drag Scrolls" http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.Drag), but I did not succeed, as well as this method - http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Scroller.

I would highly appreciate your help.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that may get you closer to solving it.  Based on my experiments, you can copy and modify dataTables.colReorder.js in function `_fnMouseMove` just before `this.dom.drag.css(...)` code.

```
var scrollLeftVal = $(this.s.dt.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft();
if((e.pageX - this.s.mouse.offsetX) > (this.s.dt.nTableWrapper.clientWidth - 50)) {
  scrollLeftVal += 10;
  $(this.s.dt.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft(scrollLeftVal);
}
```

This will scroll the window to the right when dragging a column header.  A reverse method would be needed as well, as well as modifying the positions of the pointer and drag elements, such as below:

`this.dom.pointer.css( 'left', this.s.aoTargets[i-1].x - scrollLeftVal );`

If you decided on this approach, you would be better off long term to build an extension/plugin rather than modifying core code.  This is just for experimental purposes.

I started down this path, but believe I'll do my own reordering interface since this approach, even if working and scrolling properly, is not as ideal for the project I'm working on.

Hope this helps someone get closer to a solution!

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Tested with bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/gsf2r1v4/17/

I added this code by modifying `dataTables.colReorder.js` in function `_fnMouseMove` just before `this.dom.drag.css(...)`
Seems to work Fine however with only one problem.
Lengthy columns have hard time snapping to next short width column.

For Example: in https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/gsf2r1v4/17/ , try dragging project column to next EXT column. I suspect this is because project column has larger width.

Any further fix to this problem will be much appreciated

```
var scrollHead = $(this.s.dt.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_scrollHead');
var scrollBody = $(this.s.dt.nTableWrapper).find('.dataTables_scrollBody');
var scrollLeftVal = e.pageX - scrollHead.parent().offset().left - this.s.mouse.offsetX;
//
var difference =  scrollHead[0].clientWidth  -  scrollLeftVal   ;
//is near Right edge, scroll to far right
if (difference < 150){
    scrollLeftVal = scrollHead[0].scrollWidth - scrollHead[0].clientWidth;// max scrollleft Value
}
//is near Left edge, scroll to far Left
if(scrollLeftVal < 100){
    scrollLeftVal= 0;
} 
//
scrollBody.scrollLeft(scrollLeftVal);
```